# Electron: Cannot find module 'electron-prebuilt'

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, nightmare

I have an Electron app that uses Nightmare.js when one of the buttons is clicked. It works fine before being packaged, but after I compile it to an .exe file with electron-packager, it will work as intended, until I click the button that makes use of Nightmare.js. I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'electron-prebuilt'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (C:\app-directory\app-name-win32-ia32\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418)
    at Module.require (module.js:498)
    at require (internal/module.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app-directory\app-name-win32-ia32\resources\app\node_modules\nightmare\lib\nightmare.js:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app-directory\app-name-win32-ia32\resources\app\node_modules\nightmare\lib\nightmare.js:528)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580)
    at Module.load (module.js:488)
```

Comment: posting the electron package.json would be useful or if you use a custom build script

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `electron-prebuilt` had been added into `development dependency` in your package.json . You can install module by `npm install --save-dev electron-prebuilt`

The correct way to require the app module in Electron is:

```
const {app} = require('electron')
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. I have already tried both of these, none seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: It's pretty weird, because electron-prebuilt seems to be an older name for electron, but I'm using a not so old version. Do you have any other ideas?